JWT auth works fine in postman but not in .NET 6 code
I have two applications. One is an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app, and the other is an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.
I am generating the JWT token in my Web API. When I try to access one Authorize endpoint by passing the JWT token in Postman, I am getting 200 OK response, but when I try to access the same Authorize endpoint by passing the same JWT token from my ASP.NET Core MVC application, I am getting a "401 unauthorized" response.
This is the problem which I am facing. Some one help me to resolve this issue.
Below is the ASP.NET Core MVC code which I am trying to access the endpoint:
public async Task<List<T>> GetApiList<T>(string serviceUrl, string userToken = null, bool isAuth = true) where T : new()
{
    List<T> response = new List<T>();

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Add necessary headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            // Send a GET request to the API
            HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5031/api/" + "gallery/authtestapi");

            // Ensure the request was successful
            apiResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read the response content as a string
            string responseBody = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Deserialize the JSON response into a C# object
            response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseBody);

            return response;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException httpEx)
    {
        // Log the HTTP request exception (e.g., 401 Unauthorized)
        Console.WriteLine($"HTTP Request Exception: {httpEx.Message}");
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return response;
    }
}

Below is the code which I am trying to access in the Web API:
[HttpGet]
[Route("authtestapi")]
[Authorize]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public string AuthTestApi()
{
    return "Response from authorize api";
}

Here is the API code to generate the JWT token:
//generating jwt token
var claims = new[]
             {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName),
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRoles[0])
             };

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("gdyegwuhqd9387ejnfkqk210998plnxbuqqoowsaxlKohxpqud87654hjcyg"));

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: "GShop-WEB-API-10072023-001",
                        audience: "GShop-WEB-API-10072023-001",
                        claims: claims,
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256) );

string tokenAsString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

This is the Program.cs configuration in the API code:
//add jwt authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = "GShop-WEB-API-10072023-001",
        ValidAudience = "GShop-WEB-API-10072023-001",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("gdyegwuhqd9387ejnfkqk210998plnxbuqqoowsaxlKohxpqud87654hjcyg")),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    };
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7236/", "http://localhost:5236")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Below I have tried,
I tried by removing the Authorization attribute in my controller and tried to see the headers and I see the header is null.
When I request from post man I am getting headers with JWT token as expected. But If I request the same api end point from my MVC application I am getting the header value as null, even though If I pass the JWT token.
I also tried by creating the separate console application and checked by requesting the same api end point. but still I am getting null header in my API side.
Below is my api code,
 var headers = Request.Headers;

            var userAgent = headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
            var authorization = headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            var test = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();

Below is my MVC app code,
string token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zaWQiOiJjNWU5ZjU5Zi03OGRmLTQyYTYtOWQ4Ni0zODMxNmY4YTdiM2QiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1laWRlbnRpZmllciI6ImJoYXJhdGgiLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTcyNDc0MTkxNCwiaXNzIjoiR1Nob3AtV0VCLUFQSS0xMDA3MjAyMy0wMDEiLCJhdWQiOiJHU2hvcC1XRUItQVBJLTEwMDcyMDIzLTAwMSJ9.Vi0cLnxYMXEGPinv4CyMKUVn7s12bOEMLlGaiopRq54";


using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5031/api/");
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    // Add necessary headers
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    // Send a GET request to the API
    HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.GetAsync("user/allusers");

    // Ensure the request was successful
    apiResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Read the response content as a string
    string responseBody = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Deserialize the JSON response into a C# object

}


Your codes worked well in my side. Based on your description, you can use POSTMAN and an access token to call the secured API successfully, so that I think your API should be configured well. And I also test your code used to call the API which working well too. So that I'm afraid that the token you used here might not be a correct one. I want to double confirm with you that whether you test with a hard code access token into your GetApiList<T> method? I test with the token which is used in postman test, it worked well.

when Postman works and browser doesn't it's almost always a CORS issue.  Postman does not have CORS rules... only the browser does that.  (Is this a cross-domain request?  localhosts at different ports are considered different domains for CORS rules)

@TinyWang   Yes I am using hardcoded token in my GetApiList<T> method for testing purpose. Even though If I use the same token in postman is working fine.

Thanks for your confirmation, but your codes worked in my side, I'm afraid you might need to share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue, and I think when you create that sample, you shall find the issue that time....

@browsermator I have tried by adding the cors as well, still I am facing the same issue. I am sure that my token is valid and it is not expired. I have updated the question by adding cors code which I tried.

try debugging with cors rules turned off just to rule out CORS... (disable-web-security in browser temporarily)  If it works with web security disabled, you'll know CORS is the issue.

@browsermator I checked by getting the Authorization headers from api side and I see there is nothing. But I am passing the headers with Authorization during the api call. This might be the issue? If yes how I can resolve this?

@browsermator var authHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault(); This is the code I am using in api side to get auth headers. I am getting null in this line.

@browsermator  I have updated my question. I tried by removing the Auth attribute and checked for header values and it is getting as null. But If I use the same end point from post man I am getting the header values with JWT token as expected.

@TinyWang I have updated my question. I tried by removing the Auth attribute and checked for header values and it is getting as null. But If I use the same end point from post man I am getting the header values with JWT token as expected.

Thank you for your update, but your codes looks good. Could you please create a new solution and test my codes below?

I tried your setup and I can generate the token and validate it on the API application (all localhost). Maybe you need to enable CORS if you are on different domains?
Also, try adding more logging in Program.cs:
options.TokenValidationParameters = ... // what you have already

// add debug logging
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OnAuthenticationFailed: {context.Exception.Message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnChallenge = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OnChallenge: {context.Error}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };


I have updated my question. I tried by removing the Auth attribute and checked for header values and it is getting as null. But If I use the same end point from post man I am getting the header values with JWT token as expected.

This is what I used in my app to call the web api.
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    // Add necessary headers
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbG6x9fncWTw");

    // Send a GET request to the API
    HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7035/api/hello");

    // Ensure the request was successful
    apiResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Read the response content as a string
    string responseBody = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}

And this is my api
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult getUser() {
        return Ok("hello");
    }
}

This is my jwt auth configuration.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
 .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
 {
     cfg.SaveToken = true;
     cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
     cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true,
         ValidateAudience = false,
         ValidAudience = "Test.com",
         ValidIssuer = "Test.com",
         IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"))
     };
 });

This is how I generate access token.
private string generateJwt() {
    var securityKey2 = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"));
    var credentials2 = new SigningCredentials(securityKey2, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var claims = new[] {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "user_name"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, "user_email"),
        new Claim("DateOfJoing", "2022-09-12"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("role","admin"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"admin")
    };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
        signingCredentials: credentials2);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

